# What is the meaning of be able to walk about the wards

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It's from the book a study in scarlet sir Arthur Conan Doyle.

Comment: As Watson was recovering from a bullet wound, the meaning of _able to walk about_ should be obvious. You may have been unaware of the relevant meaning of _ward_, which the answer explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *ward* is specific area or wing of a hospital that usually serves a specific type of patient (as in a maternity ward or psychiatric ward). To "be able to walk about the wards" indicates that one can walk about the hospital. It's a sign that a previously bedridden patient's condition is improving as they regain mobility. They're not well enough yet to leave the hospital, but they are no longer confined to their own bed/room.

Comment: And in the US anyway, it can also refer to subregions—usually political—of a city.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - in the UK too.

Comment: But not in this case, where Dr Watson is referring to his convalescence after being wounded in battle.